# Rails: bi-directional has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have three models in a Rails application: `Game` represents an instance of a game being played. `Player` represents an instance of a participant in a game. `User` represents a registered person who can participate in games.

Each `Game` can have many `Players`, and each `User` can have many `Players` (a single person can participate in multiple games at once); but each `Player` is in precisely one `Game`, and represents precisely one `User`. Hence, my relationships are as follows at present.

```
class Game
  has_many :players
end

class User
  has_many :players
end

class Player
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user
end
```

... where naturally the `players` table has `game_id` and `user_id` columns, but `games` and `users` have no foreign keys.

I would also like to represent the fact that each `Game` has many `Users` playing in it; and each `User` has many `Games` in which they are playing. How do I do this? Is it enough to add

```
class Game
  has_many :users, :through => :players
end

class User
  has_many :games, :through => :players
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose should be enough; Now, each game should have a users[] array, and each user has a games[] array.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

:has_many :through is basically an extension of the typical many-to-many model where you have an intermediate table with ids for each one of the related entities. However, in Rails, the :has_and_belongs_to_many relationship doesn't allow for the intermediate table to be an entity in itself, in that it has no meaning other than serving as glue between the two related models.

:has_many :through allows a real entity or model in the application (in your case, players) to act as "glue" between two others (games, users) but also allowing you to manipulate "players" as in this case it does contain important information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can't believe I've not come across the Guides before! I've basically be working from "agile web dev", which mentions the article->section->paragraph case, but doesn't really cover the "HABTM with a real middle" case.